# excel date formatting not working

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an excel sheet created by a 3rd party program.

One of the columns has dates in this format: "Jan 19, 2015 03:00:00 PM"

I would like these dates to appear in the following format: "19/01/2015"

I have selected the cell or cells, right clicked and selected "Format Cells...", chose "Date" in the category, then chose "14/03/2001" in the type, to no avail, the dates won't change.

I also tried "Custom" from the category and "dd/mm/yyyy" from the type, again, no changes at all.

The file is not protected, the sheet is editable.

Could someone explain what I could be doing wrong?

Regards
Crouz

Comment: What *country* version of Excel are you using?  If you go to the "Region and Language" dialog from Control Panel, and look at the Formats Tab, what language(country) is listed in the Format:  line

Comment: @Paresh - Custom format isn't an option, although as stated in the question I did select all cells and after a right click I selected "Format Cells..." to no avail

Comment: OK, then it is Text, and the reason for that is the discrepancy between the date being entered (US format), and the date Excel can interpret (UK format).  See my answer for a solution.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Mine is English(United States). I'm facing exactly same issue as described in the question above. Please help?

Comment: @RehanKhan What happened when you tried the accepted answer?

Comment: Nothing happened cause I didn't do anything. Since 'Region and Language' settings were already set to ' English(United States)' and not UK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your regional settings (UK), and the inability of formatting to change the date, your date-time string is text.  The following formula will convert the date part to a "real" date, and you can then apply the formatting you wish:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,5),MATCH(LEFT(A1,3),{"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec"},0),MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","   "),5,5))
```

Might be able to simplify a bit with more information as to the input format, but the above should work fine.  Also, if you need to retain the Time portion, merely append:

```
+RIGHT(A1,11)
```

to the above formula.

Comment: Writing your own date-time demogrifizer code is never a safe idea.  See thedailywtf for multiple examples of this sort of thing going wrong.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft In general, you are correct. The safest way in Excel to handle this sort of problem will always be before it gets to Excel, usually by importing instead of opening a csv file. In this particular case, since it was described as an Excel Sheet generated by a third party, and all of the dates were text strings in a known format, I provided a solution that did not involve modifying the third-party application. But I expect that it would only work for this particular type of problem.

Answer (score 65):

The following worked for me:

- Select the date column.
- Go to the Data-tab and choose "Text to Columns".
- On the first screen, leave radio button on "delimited" and click Next.
- Unselect any delimiter boxes (everything blank) and click Next.
- Under column data format choose Date
- Click Finish.

Now you got date values

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much, worked for me too. I was scratching my head for the last 30 min.

Comment: Perfect answer!! But what is the mystery behind it?

Comment: (+1) I'm not sure why this works, but I found that even after trying to edit the date format following @Crouzilles above, it wouldn't register until I actually selected the cell by double-clicking and then hitting enter. That's obviously burdensome for an entire column, but I think answer somehow overcomes that.

Comment: Question. Even though I have my desired format, when I double-click in the cell to change the date, it reverts to the original date format until I click out of the cell. This doesn't happen with my instructor's dataset even though it's the same dataset. She is in UK so her format is UK. When I opened the file it was US format so I changed it to UK. But as I said, when I edit the cell, it temporarily reverts back to US format until I click out. Maybe I have to change Excel's app preferences to UK?

Comment: Perfect. Saved me from going hulk smash

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My Excel sheet had 102,300 rows and one column with date was messy. No amount of tricks were working. spent a whole day entering crazy formulas online to no success. See the snips

1. How the column looked ("Short Date" format on Excel)

The red circled cell contents (problematic ones) do not change at all regardless of what tricks you do. Including deleting them manually and entering the figures in "DD-MM-YYYY" format, or copying and pasting format from the blue ones. Basically, nothing worked...STUBBORNNESS!!

[image: cells]

2. How the column looked ("Long date" format on Excel)

As can be seen, the cell contents doesn't change no matter what.

[image: column]

3. How I solved it

The only way to solve this is to:

1. upload the Excel sheet to Google Drive. On Google Drive do this:
2. click to open the file with Google spreadsheet
3. Once it has opened as a Google spreadsheet, select the entire column with dates.
4. select the format type to Date (you can choose any format of date you want).
5. Download the Google spreadsheet as .xlsx. All the contents of the column are now dates

Comment: Thank you sir, Its really help me.

Answer (score 1):

`DATEVALUE` function will help if date is stored as a text as in

`=DATEVALUE("Jan 19, 2015 03:00:00 PM")`

Answer (score 1):

My solution to a similar problem with Date formatting was solved by:

1. Copying the problem sheet then pasting it into Sheet
   n.
2. Deleting the problem sheet.
3. Renaming Sheet n to the name of the problem sheet.

QED.

The problem sheet contained Date data that I wanted to read as 07/21/2017 that would not display anything other than 42937. The first thing I did was to close Excel and re-launch it. More tries followed. I gave up on my own solutions. I tried a few online suggestions. I then made one more attempt and - **Walla** - the above three steps fixed the problem.  As to why the problem existed? It obviously had something to do with "the" sheet. Go figure!

For me to believe is insufficient for you to know - rodalsa.

Answer (score 0):

With your data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,12))
```

and format **B1** as *dd/mm/yyyy* For example:

[image]

If the cell appears to have a date/time, but it does not respond to format changes, it is probably a *Text* value rather than a genuine date/time.

Answer (score 0):

While you didn't tag VBA as a possible solution, you may be able to use what some feel is a VBA shortcoming to your advantage; that being VBA heavily defaulted to North American regional settings unless explicitly told to use another.

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull down menus to Insert ► Module (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the following into the pane titles something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*.

```
Sub mdy_2_dmy_by_Sel()
    Dim rDT As Range
    With Selection
        .Replace what:=Chr(160), replacement:=Chr(32), lookat:=xlPart
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
        For Each rDT In .Cells
            rDT = CDate(rDT.Value2)
        Next rDT
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With
End Sub
```

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet. Select all of the dates (just the dates, not the whole column) and tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to **Run** the macro.

Note that both date and time are preserved. Change the cell number format if you wish to see the underlying times as well as the dates.

Comment: VBA is smart enough that I think you can just do:  `rDT = CDate(rDT)`  At least here (in the US, using the UK regional settings, and replacing all the `SPACE` with `NBSP`), it will still do the conversion correctly, with no `TTC` or replacing the `NBSP`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I was concerned that there were underlying factors (e.g. the *non-breaking space* I attempted to cover) that were stopping **Jan 19, 2015 03:00:00 PM** from being converted and wanted to cover as many bases as I could. Certainly *Jan*- is used on both sides of the pond and the date should have been recognized at the outset. The last step of cycling through the cell one-by-one may not even be necessary if non-breaking spaces are removed and the column is treated to a Text-to-Columns ► Fixed width.

Comment: My point is that VBA recognized the string as a date even with NBSP's being present within, before and after the string.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this issue for 20 mins today. My issue was the same as MARIO's in this thread, but my solution is easier. If you look at his answer above, the blue circled dates are "month/day/year", and the red dates are "day/month/year". Changing the red date format to match the blue date format, then selecting all of them, right click, Format Cells, Category "Date", select the Type desired. The Red dates can be changed manually, or use some other excel magic to swap the day and month.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to address a few cells in one column that won't convert is to copy them off to Notepad, then `CLEAR ALL` (formatting and contents) those cells and paste the cell contents in Notepad back into the same cells.

Then you can set them as Date, or Text or whatever.

Clear Formatting did not work for me. **Excel 365**, probably version **2019**.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you want to format.
Press CTRL+1.
In the Format Cells box, click the Number tab.
In the Category list, click Date.
Under Type, pick a date format.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this is to:

upload the Excel sheet to Google Drive. On Google Drive do this:

click to open the file with Google spreadsheet

Once it has opened as a Google spreadsheet, select the entire column with dates.

select the format type to Date (you can choose any format of date you want).

Download the Google spreadsheet as .xlsx. All the contents of the column are now dates

Answer (score 0):

Select the column ->
Go to "Data" Tab -> Select "Text to Column" ->
Select Delimited -> check Tab ( uncheck other boxes) -> Select Date -> Change format to MMDDYYY -> Finish.

Answer (score -1):

Similar way as ron rosefield but a little bit simplified.

=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MATCH(MID(A1,4,2),{"01";"02";"03";"04";"05";"06";"07";"08";"09";"10";"11";"12"},0),LEFT(A1,2))