# Calculate between 2 dates and time on Excel

Tags: excel

The date/time are imported for different sources and are in thus the different formats

2020-07-11 1238  and Jul 12, 2020 10:15 am

Would preferable result in minutes or hours and minutes

Comment: I think you need to convert those strings to a valid date, like is don here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516923/excel-date-formatting-not-working

Comment: Is there no colon on this date/time: 2020-07-11 1238? Do you intend to use VBA?

Comment: It needs more sample data for "2020-07-11 1238". Granting that the sample time is 12:38, how does it represent the time before noon time? For example, is it 0001 for 12:01 at midnight?

Comment: @WilsMils:   `noon time`  